# How to represent highest and lowest values with > <?

Tags: r, raster

I have a raster and when I plot it, I got the legend as a rectangle.I am asked to plot the legend as the one in this graph (two arrows on bottom and top).

[image]

The colours in the triangles to represent all values above 15 and below -10. If the triangles are difficult to put on the legend.Is it possible to just put at 
symbols > < before 15 AND 10!.

```
    on the top > 15   and on the bottom < -10
library(raster)
r <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10); r <- setValues(r, 1:ncell(r))
plot(r)
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to convey the same message is, as you say, indicating that the bottom and top colours represent "less than -10" and "greater than 15". This is equivalent to saying the ends of the ramp are negative infinity and positive infinity, respectively.

Here's how you might do that with `rasterVis::levelplot`:

```
# First, some fake data
r <- raster(matrix(runif(100, -20, 30), 10))

library(rasterVis)
levelplot(r, margin=FALSE, at=c(-Inf, seq(-10, 15, 2.5), Inf), 
          colorkey=list(at=seq(-12.5, 17.5, 2.5),
                        labels=c(expression(-infinity), 
                                 seq(-10, 15, 2.5), 
                                 expression(infinity)))
)
```

[image]

Above, the `at` argument to `levelplot` controls the breaks at which colours in the plot will change. We set it such that values between `-Inf` and -10 are one colour, and then colours change every 2.5 units, until 15, after which colour is constant up to `Inf`. The `at` element of the `colorkey` list controls the colour breaks for the colour legend. Negative and positive infinity will be represented by -12.5 and 17.5. The `labels` element of `colorkey` determines the labels that will be plotted at those locations. We can use an `expression` to include an infinity symbol.

If you want to use a diverging ramp, you could calculate an appropriate ramp manually according to the length of the negative vs. positive sides of the ramp. For example, in the example above, we need 7 positive colours and 5 negative colours, so we can create a ramp of 14 colours, and exclude the first 2:

```
library(RColorBrewer)
colr <- colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(11, 'RdBu')))(14)[3:14]
```

Then pass this ramp to `col.regions`:

```
levelplot(r, margin=FALSE, at=c(-Inf, seq(-10, 15, 2.5), Inf), 
      colorkey=list(at=seq(-12.5, 17.5, 2.5),
                    labels=c(expression(-infinity), 
                             seq(-10, 15, 2.5), 
                             expression(infinity))),
      col.regions=colr
)
```

[image]

Comment: I haven't used rasterVis much. But it seems like syntax is simple; you explained how to do the job clearly. +1

Comment: @jazzurro - thanks, I work with raster data a lot, and `rasterVis` has been a lifesaver. It uses `lattice`, so more or less follows `lattice` syntax (e.g. `?lattice::levelplot`).

Comment: I see. I kinda skipped the lattice era and started using ggplot. Since I got some data analysis and visualization for spatial data, I think it is worth digging rasterVis. Thanks for this post!

Comment: @temor - You can pass a character vector to `labels`, but if you label the bottom end as `< -10`, how do you interpret the area between `-10` and `< -10`?

Comment: @temor - totally up to you, but to me, the bin "between -7.5 and less than -10" doesn't really make sense. It would be like changing -10 to < -10 in the example image you posted.

Comment: If you really must do that, then you can do something like `colorkey=list(at=seq(-12.5, 17.5, 2.5), labels=c('', '< -10', seq(-7.5, 12.5, 2.5), '> 15', ''))`. It doesn't make sense to label a break point as _less than (or greater than) some value_. Labelling the bottom _bin_ as `< -10` would make more sense.

Comment: To label the top and bottom _bin_ in that way, you could do `colorkey=list(at=seq(-12.5, 17.5, 2.5), labels=list(at=c(-11.25, seq(-10, 15, 2.5), 16.25), labels=c('< -10', seq(-10, 15, 2.5), '> 15')))`.